# How can we get access to SQLContext in a flatmap function?

Tags: apache-spark

SQlContext when accessed as below using a singleton class works fine in local mode, however when submitted spark master, it becomes null and throws nullpointer exceptions. How can this be fixed?
In our usecase FlatMapFunction is expected to query another DStream and the results returned are used to create a new stream.

Have extended the JavaStatefulNetworkWordCount example to print the changes to the state. I need to access the rdds from a stateful dstream in another dstream using sqlcontext in order to create another dstream. How can this be achieved?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.StorageLevels;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;

import scala.Tuple2;

import com.google.common.base.Optional;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class JavaStatefulNetworkWordCount {
  private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length < 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: JavaStatefulNetworkWordCount <hostname> <port>");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    // Update the cumulative count function
    final Function2<List<Integer>, Optional<Integer>, Optional<Integer>> updateFunction =
        new Function2<List<Integer>, Optional<Integer>, Optional<Integer>>() {
          @Override
          public Optional<Integer> call(List<Integer> values, Optional<Integer> state) {

            Integer newSum = state.or(0);
            for (Integer value : values) {
              newSum += value;
            }
            return Optional.of(newSum);
          }
        };

    // Create the context with a 1 second batch size
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaStatefulNetworkWordCount");
//    sparkConf.setMaster("local[5]");
//  sparkConf.set("spark.executor.uri", "target/rkspark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar");
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(1));
    ssc.checkpoint(".");
    SQLContext sqlContext = JavaSQLContextSingleton.getInstance(ssc.sparkContext().sc());
    // Initial RDD input to updateStateByKey
    List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> tuples = Arrays.asList(new Tuple2<String, Integer>("hello", 1),
            new Tuple2<String, Integer>("world", 1));
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> initialRDD = ssc.sc().parallelizePairs(tuples);

    JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = ssc.socketTextStream(
            args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]), StorageLevels.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2);

    JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
      @Override
      public Iterable<String> call(String x) {
        return Lists.newArrayList(SPACE.split(x));
      }
    });

    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordsDstream = words.mapToPair(
        new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
          @Override
          public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
            return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
          }
        });

    // This will give a Dstream made of state (which is the cumulative count of the words)
    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> stateDstream = wordsDstream.updateStateByKey(updateFunction,
            new HashPartitioner(ssc.sparkContext().defaultParallelism()), initialRDD);
    JavaDStream<WordCount> countStream = stateDstream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, Integer>, WordCount>(){
        @Override
        public WordCount call(Tuple2<String, Integer> v1) throws Exception {
            return new WordCount(v1._1,v1._2);
        }});  
    countStream.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<WordCount>,Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call(JavaRDD<WordCount> rdd) {
          SQLContext sqlContext = JavaSQLContextSingleton.getInstance(rdd.context());
          DataFrame wordsDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, WordCount.class);
          wordsDataFrame.registerTempTable("words");
          return null;
        }
      });
    wordsDstream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String,Integer>,String>(){

        @Override
        public String call(Tuple2<String, Integer> v1) throws Exception {
            // Below sql context becomes null when run on a master instead of local.            
            SQLContext sqlContext = JavaSQLContextSingleton.getInstance();
            DataFrame counterpartyIds = sqlContext.sql("select * from words where word ='"+v1._1()+"'");
            Row[] rows = counterpartyIds.cache().collect();
            if(rows.length>0){
                Row row = rows[0];
                return row.getInt(0)+"-"+ row.getString(1);
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }).print();
    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();
  }
}
class JavaSQLContextSingleton {
  static private transient SQLContext instance = null;
  static public SQLContext getInstance(SparkContext sparkContext) {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new SQLContext(sparkContext);
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
   import java.io.Serializable;
    public class WordCount implements Serializable{
    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }
    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
    String word;
    public WordCount(String word, int count) {
        super();
        this.word = word;
        this.count = count;
    }
    int count;
   }
```

Comment: I think you forgot the code?

Comment: @runDOSrun - Just added the code.

Answer (score 3):

The SparkContext (and thus the SQLContext) is only available in the Driver and not serialized to the Workers. Your program works in local since it is running in the context of the driver where the context is available.

Comment: I need to access the rdds from a stateful dstream in another dstream using sqlcontext in order to create another dstream. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you should use transform to create a new DStream from a DStream or use foreachRDD where you can use SQLContext -see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations